# Best way to deal with huge postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql, bigdata, query-optimization

I've created a scraper that collects huge amounts of data to the Postgres database. One of the tables has more than 120 million records and still grows.
It creates obvious problems with even simple selects, but when I run aggregate
functions like `COUNT()`, it takes ages to get a result. I want to display this data using a web service, but it is definitely too slow to do it directly. I thought about materialized views, but even there if I run some more advanced query (query with subqueries to show trend) it throws an error with not enough memory, and if the query is simple, then it takes about an hour to complete. I am asking about general rules (I haven't managed to find any) with dealing with such huge databases.
The example queries which I use:

The simple query takes about an hour to complete (Items table have 120 million records, ItemTypes have about 30k - they keep the names and all information for the Items)

```
SELECT 
  IT."name", 
  COUNT("Items".id) AS item_count,
  (CAST(COUNT("Items".id) AS DECIMAL(10,1))/(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM "Items"))*100 as percentage_of_all
FROM "Items" JOIN "ItemTypes" IT on "Items"."itemTypeId" = IT.id
GROUP BY IT."name"
ORDER BY item_count  DESC;
```

When I run the above query with subquery which returns `COUNT("Items".id) AS item_count` % trend which is the count of them from a week ago compared to count now, it throws an error that memory was exceeded.

As I wrote above I am looking for tips, how to optimize it. The first thing I plan to optimize the above query is to move names from ItemTypes to Items, to Items. It won't be required to join ItemTypes anymore, but I already tried to mock it and the results aren't a lot better.

Comment: You can make it slightly faster by using `count(*)` instead - but not very much.

Comment: The "general rule" is to solve the specific problems you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery, so an equivalent version is:

```
SELECT IT."name", 
       COUNT(*) AS item_count,
       COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as percentage_of_all
FROM "Items" JOIN 
     "ItemTypes" IT 
     ON "Items"."itemTypeId" = IT.id
GROUP BY IT."name"
ORDER BY item_count  DESC;
```

I'm not sure if this will fix your resource problem.  In addition, this assumes that all items have a valid `ItemType`.  If that is not the case, use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.